# Wear addListener's onDataChanged isn't being called

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm encountering a very weird scenario. I implemented both `WearableListenerService` and `Wearable.DataApi.addListener` on my wear device, and I am periodically sending data updates from my phone. The `WearableListenerService` is properly getting `onDataChanged` callbacks, but my listener in the main activity isn't..

This is my setup for the activity:

```
onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(googleApiClient, this);
    super.onStop();
}

onConnected() {
    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(googleApiClient, this);
}

onDataChanged() {
    // never gets called
}
```

I can post more code, but above is the general gist. On the other hand, my `WearableListenerService` is properly declared in the `AndroidManifest`, and simply prints out logs when it receives `onDataChanged`.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: is "onConnected()" called?

Comment: Yup, `onConnected` is properly getting called, I even added a callback for `addListener`, and it's properly adding the listener.

Comment: and in those cases that your onDataChanged() is not called in this live listener, the one in your WerableListenerService is called?

Comment: Yeah the service is getting the callback but not the activity that called `addListener`.

Comment: Can you build a simple project that would exhibit this issue and share the project?

Comment: Did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to implement one of the following interfaces in your activity:

- DataApi.DataListener
- MessageApi.MessageListener
- NodeApi.NodeListener

See 'With a Listener Activity' part of [this](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html) android developer documentation.